# Power BI custom visuals - $ is not a function when trying to load jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, typescript, npm, datatables, powerbi

what may cause `$ is not a function` error when developing custom Power Bi Visuals via using Pbiviz?

The problem occurs when I want to specify jquery plugins. Looks like wrong libraries order but the output file has proper one.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "out": "./.tmp/build/visual.js"
  },
  "files": [
    ".api/v1.7.0/PowerBI-visuals.d.ts",
    "src/settings.ts",
    "src/visual.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/datatables.net/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils/lib/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

pbiviz.json:

```
  "externalJS": [
    "node_modules/powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils/lib/index.js",
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
    "node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js"
  ],
```

package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.48",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.50",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
    "jquery": "^2.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils": "1.2.0"
  },
```

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at <anonymous>:14820:21
    at <anonymous>:10387:3
    at Window.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:10390:1)
    at <anonymous>:25969:20
    at Object.r [as injectJsCode] (visualhostcore.min.js:2)
    at i.loadWithoutResourcePackage (visualsandbox.min.js:1)
    at i.executeMessage (visualsandbox.min.js:1)
    at i.onMessageReceived (visualsandbox.min.js:1)
    at visualsandbox.min.js:1
    at e.invokeHandler (visualhostcore.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the sandbox, all custom visuals work in the sandbox, where window object is fake windows object.

Try to the following way:

Create js file with following code:

```
var jQuery = typeof jQuery !== 'undefined'
    ? jQuery
    : window['$'];
```

and include this file to externalJS section of pbiviz.json.
But put the row between
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
and 
"node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js",
(so, after jquery, but before jquery plugins)

Sample:
https://github.com/Microsoft/powerbi-visuals-heatmap/blob/master/pbiviz.json#L24